# How to scale a texture and save the result in another in XNA

Tags: xna

I'm new to XNA. What I want is just to scale a texture (double its size for example) and save the bigger one in another texture object of type Texture2D..

Any Ideas?

thanks..

Note::

I know how to view a texture in a different scale,, take this piece of code:

CountryTexturData = new Color[CountryTextur.Width * CountryTextur.Height];

CountryTextur.GetData(CountryTexturData);

I want to make a process on the pixels of the country, but not the original one (CountryTextur), I want the scaled one, to save its pixels data in an array, like CountryTextureData, then make a simple process..

SpriteBatch.Draw only can view it scaled,, hopefully I could explain the problem..

Comment: that's not very useful, you will waste a lot a ram for something that gpu gives you for free.

Comment: Ok, fine..

take a sprite name: "County"

how can I have that sprite's size doubled? I don't mean in Draw function, but actually doubled..

something related to Transformation??

thanks..

Comment: `SpriteBatch.Draw` has a scale parameter. Check MSDN.

Comment: I've edited my question and added more details, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RenderTargets to achieve what you want to do:

```
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(scaledCountryTextur);
spriteBatch.Begin();
    //Draw your scaled CountryTextur
spriteBatch.End();
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

//You can now use scaledCountryTextur as an enlarged Texture2D of CountryTextur
```

What this will do is it will 'draw' your ContryTexture in a RenderTarget, which can be used like a regular Texture2D.

Hope this helps!